# How to replace \\\ 3 consecutive backslashes to 2 \\ in js using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace 3 `\\\` consecutive backslashes to `\\`. Is it possible?

I tried these options:

```js
const str="example\\\\\\txt";
str.replace(new RegExp('\\{3}','g'),'\\\\')
```

Here replace is any js string prototypes default method

this never creates a regexp object :

```
new RegExp('\\\\\\','g')
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please provide a more specific title?

Comment: ...and some example data, and the function `replace()`. Without knowing what it does it's hard to tell for sure, but you seem to be trying to replace 3 backslashes with 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match exactly 3 backslashes, you should surround the match with non-backslash matches.

```js
const regex = /(^|[^\\])\\{3}($|[^\\])/g;
const text = "2->\\\\3->\\\\\\4->\\\\\\\\";

console.log(text);
console.log(text.replace(regex, "$1\\\\$2"));
```

The above replaces 3 backslashes with 2 backslashes, but only if there are exactly 3.

Here is the regex diagram to better explain what the regex is matching.

[image: regex diagram]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%28%5E%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%29%5C%5C%7B3%7D%28%24%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%29)</sup>

---

Alternatively you could also use a negative look behind/forward. Though they are not yet everywhere [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility) (Safari doesn't support them yet).

```js
const regex = /(?<!\\)\\{3}(?!\\)/g;
const text = "2->\\\\3->\\\\\\4->\\\\\\\\";

console.log(text);
console.log(text.replace(regex, "\\\\"));
```

---

The reason `new RegExp('\\\\\\','g')` doesn't do what you want is because the backslashes need to be escaped because you are in string context.

`new RegExp('\\\\\\','g')` will create the regex `/\\\/g` which isn't a valid regex.

To solve the issue you should escape the backslashes in string context.

```
new RegExp('\\\\\\','g') // produces /\\\/g
// should be
new RegExp('\\\\\\\\\\\\','g') // produces /\\\\\\/g
```

Comment: Already had answers. Just modified my question to improve its vote

Comment: @ShyamSundarR I've updated the answer to include your issues with the regex constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rgex literal instead of `RegExp`:

```
var s='Bob\\\\\\Jones';

var r = s.replace(/\\{3}/g, '\\');
//=> Bob\Jones
```

Regex `/\\{3}/` matches 3 consecutive instances of `\`

Comment: Now is it possible to match strings that have closing braces without preceded by something. I tried :

new RegExp('(?<!\\\\")\)','g')

but dint work out

Comment: Sorry but your question is `replace 3 \\\ consecutive backslashes to \` and this is the answer for that. If your requirements have changed then edit your question and provide it there.